# Ubuntu 12.04LTS - Dash home application question mark icon

Tags: icons, unity-dash, menu

I have installed PhpStorm application in my Ubuntu 12.04 but in the Dash Home (and in Dash Bar also) appears a Question Mark icon.

[image: phpstorm icon]

I have tried to re-config the shorcut, but it not works (just the icon, the app open when I click it). Here is my *.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=JetBrains PhpStorm
GenericName=JetBrains PhpStorm
X-GNOME-FullName=Php Storm PHP IDE
Exec="/opt/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
TryExec="/opt/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
Icon="/opt/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.png"
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

In /opt/..../phpstorm.png I have my 128x128px icon.

**How to show fine my icon??**

I also have tried to use xpm icon or the default PhpStorm icon, but it does not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the reason:

ls -all

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 nov 10 18:04 google
drwxr-x---  7 root root 4096 nov 11 12:28 PhpStorm
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 nov 10 21:28 VBoxGuestAdditions-4.2.4
```

setting up the permissions like the google chrome folder everything works!

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 nov 10 18:04 google
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 nov 11 12:28 PhpStorm
```